# init error: file missing - cl-generic after any time I edit settings.org file

Tags: init-file, debugging, use-package, ein

I am using org mode to organize my various Emacs settings. Within my init.el file I just have (taking out initial comments):

```
;;; Code:
(package-initialize)
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))
(org-babel-load-file
 (expand-file-name "settings.org"
           user-emacs-directory))
```

My settings.org file is too long to post here, but if the details of it are pertinent I put the whole thing into a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/STkz1ADQ
(The section about ein is at the bottom)

Recently (I don't know when this issue cropped up, I hadn't touched my settings.org in a while), any time I edit my settings.org file I get the following error message upon re-loading Emacs:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/dan/.emacs.d/init.el':

File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, cl-generic
```

The full debug message:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "no such file or directory" "cl-generic")
  require(cl-generic)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-973163> nil "/home/dan/.emacs.d/elpa/ein-20160107.455/ein-cell-output.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1010
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/dan/.emacs.d/elpa/ein-20160107.455/ein-cell-output.el" "/home/dan/.emacs.d/elpa/ein-20160107.455/ein-cell-output.el" nil t)
  require(ein-cell-output)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-288601> nil "/home/dan/.emacs.d/elpa/ein-20160107.455/ein-notebook.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1628
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/dan/.emacs.d/elpa/ein-20160107.455/ein-notebook.el" "/home/dan/.emacs.d/elpa/ein-20160107.455/ein-notebook.el" nil t)
  require(ein-notebook)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-347368> nil "/home/dan/.emacs.d/elpa/ein-20160107.455/ein-notebooklist.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1026
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/dan/.emacs.d/elpa/ein-20160107.455/ein-notebooklist.el" "/home/dan/.emacs.d/elpa/ein-20160107.455/ein-notebooklist.el" nil t)
  require(ein-notebooklist)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-648891> nil "/home/dan/.emacs.d/elpa/ein-20160107.455/ein-org.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 896
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/dan/.emacs.d/elpa/ein-20160107.455/ein-org.el" "/home/dan/.emacs.d/elpa/ein-20160107.455/ein-org.el" nil t)
  ein:org-store-link()
  #[(f) "\302   \205\f
```

Reading through this the issue seemed to be that something weird was going on with EIN (Emacs Ipython Notebook). So I removed ein, and reinstalled it, and the issue went away.

I have to do this (remove ein, re-install ein) any time I edit settings.org.

I have no idea why this is happening - whether it's something with my setup, or with ein, or what. What is cl-generic (brief googling hasn't turned up much information)?

The compile log for ein also makes mention of cl-generic: http://pastebin.com/1zgQXvsx

Any light anyone can shed on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess it's a bug in `ein` that it doesn't declare a dependency on [cl-generic](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/cl-generic.html)?

Comment: can you elaborate a bit? I'm not sure what I'm looking at, and don't want to bring this to the ein dev if it's something with how i have emacs set up

Comment: Library `ein-cell-output` apparently requires library `cl-generic`. Do you have a library named `cl-generic` in your `load-path`? If not, then that's why it cannot be found. Some recent versions of Emacs have library `cl-generic`, but older versions do not have it. Presumably `ein` requires such a recent version of Emacs.

Comment: [cl-generic](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/cl-generic.html) says it "provides (a subset of) the features ... introduced in Emacs-25" so `ein` should have `(cl-generic "0.2")` (or `(emacs "25")` if the subset is not sufficient) listed as a dependency in its `ein-pkg.el` file.

Comment: I didn't realize cl-generic was a package (was under the impression it was included). Manually installing it seems to have fixed the issue. Still would love to know why this cropped up all of the sudden. I'm also using the most up to date stable release of Emacs (24.5.1)